# Animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I wanted to make a matplotlib animation of trig functions in unit circle, so far I've menaged to get the still plot. I've done the exact same thing in PyGame but it has really bad antialiasing so I moved to matplotlib. I was thinking of achieving the animation effect by increasing the angle in each frame of animation but I just don't know how to make it work in matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patheffects import withStroke

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

angle = np.pi / 6
x = [0, np.cos(angle)]
y = [0, np.sin(angle)]

ax.set_ylim((-1.5, 1.5))
ax.set_xlim((-1.5, 1.5))


def center_origin():
    # Getting rid of axis values
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # Move left y-axis and bottom x-axis to centre, passing through (0,0)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

    # Eliminate upper and right axes
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')


def circle(x, y, radius=0.15):

    circle = plt.Circle((x, y), radius, clip_on=False, zorder=10, linewidth=1,
                    edgecolor='black', facecolor=(0, 0, 0, .0125),
                    path_effects=[withStroke(linewidth=1)])
    ax.add_artist(circle)


circle(0, 0, 1)

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot([x[1], x[1]], [y[0], y[1]])
ax.plot([x[0], x[1]], [y[1], y[1]])

center_origin()

plt.show()
```

Comment: There are [a lot of examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#animation) on how to animate plots in matplotlib. I guess it would make sense to at least try to implement it and in addition clearly state what you want to achieve and at which point you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it